# Difference between InstanceID and ImageID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-ami

I am currently working on some IAM policies on AWS and being asked to specify Instance and Image ID. I am not sure what is the difference between the two. From what I understand and instanceID is the one that starts with ami-XXXXXX. Correct me if I am wrong, if that is the case where can I find imageID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in following ways :-

*First make sure you are using the new EC2 Experience* ( these are applicable on updated UI)

1. Now log in to your console.
2. Go to EC2 instances.
3. You will see resources, under resources click on **instances (all states)**.

Note :- **You have chosen the right region**.

4. Click onleft check box for the instance you want to find details ; in the bottom of the screen under `Details` you can find instance id starting with **i-***** and further scroll it you will get `ami id` starting with **ami-***** also.
   [image]

Comment: where can I find the instance ID which starts from i-XXXX

Comment: yes of course thats your instance id and aim id started with ami

Comment: Thanks I found it.

Comment: DO upvote it, if you find it useful so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

**imageId** often starts with "ami-" and you can find it in `EC2/Images/AMIs`
**instanceId** is the id of instance, you can find it in list of your instances `EC2/Instances/Instances->Instance ID field`

Answer (score 0):

The ID of an **Amazon EC2 instance** looks like: `i-xxxx`

The ID of an Amazon Machine Image (**AMI**) looks like: `ami-xxxx`

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched, the contents of the AMI is copied to the disks of the new instance.

Comment: where can I find the instance ID which starts from i-XXXX

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. Are you asking where to find the Instance ID for a particular instance? It appears in the console, as shown by @Jatin (with the orange line).

Comment: Yeah, exactly InstanceID. Thanks.